# How to add space between elements in nested arrays using .join method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning JavaScript and in Arrays part I've got some question when I use `.join` in array with nested array.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5];


console.log(arr.join(', '));


// Output 1, 2, 3, 4,5
```

How can I get result that include space between 4 and 5?

```
Like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: `console.log(arr.map(e => e.length ? e.join(', ') : e).join(', '));`

Comment: You can flatten an array, and then join them using space: `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]].flat().join(' ');`. Read more about array.flat() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: `console.log(arr.flat().join(', '));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]];
const mergedNestedArrays = [].concat.apply([], myArray)

console.log(mergedNestedArrays.join(', '));
```

First you need to merge/flatten your nested arrays then apply `join()` method. Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use flat

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]];
console.log(arr.flat())
```

Comment: Your array is malformed.